# Common mistakes in concluding that series is convergent or not

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assuming $(na_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ convergent to $0$ then

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is convergent, true or false ?

wel' I say it is true because:

$n$ convergent to infinity and $na_{n}$ is convergent to zero

meaning is also convergent to zero.

So the question who is "convergent faster".

I can conclude that $a_{n}$ is convergent faster then $\frac{1}{n}$ to $0$

because $n\frac{1}{n}$ convergent to $1$.

meaning $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{> 1}\ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}\ \forall n>N \ a_{n} \leq \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$

And we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ is convergent there fore the tail of  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is convergent meaning the series is convergent.

I was told this is not true and the answer is false.

So can someone please give a counterexample and please explain to me what I did wrong in my proof.

Thanks in advanced !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because $na_n \to 0$, it doesn't follow that $a_n < n^{-\alpha}$ for some $\alpha > 1$.

Counterexample: $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n\log n}$. The corresponding series diverges; the simplest way to see this is via the integral test (or Cauchy's condensation test if you know that one).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n}
$$
is divergent, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n \log n}=0$.